# Basic Sublime Text Plugin Development: view.run_command('example') does not work

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to use Will Bond's guide to creating a Sublime Text plugin (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685).

Step 1 of the guide says to create a default plugin with the following code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

This plugin gets saved as Prefixr.py in:

```
Sublime_Text_3_Location/Packages/Prefixr
```

I then type the following command into the Sublime Text console:

```
view.run_command('example')
```

And this should insert "Hello, World!" at the beginning of my currently viewed file.

However, when I enter the command, nothing happens. No "Hello, World!" appears in my file. Restarting Sublime Text does not fix it. Neither does running the command from different files.

Any idea why the command does not work?

Comment: Works fine for me using ST3 on Win7. I saved the file in `Packages/User`, as that is the preferred location for custom plugins.

Comment: What is the complete path of the location that you saved your file at? You may have saved it in the wrong directory.

Comment: I believe I have figured out my error. Two things were occurring. 1) I was mistakenly saving the plugin folder in the Packages/User folder. Sublime apparently does not search that deep for plugins. 2) Even if I saved the plugin folder higher up in the Packages folder, any typo in the plugin code would cause the plugin not to run but would not display an error calling out the typo. So to summarize, I fixed this problem by saving my plugin folder under the Packages folder and ensuring my plugin code has no typos.

Comment: It should definitely be searching within the `Packages/User` folder. It doesn't search anything deeper than that, but it should find `Packages/User/example.py`, for example. As for typos, typos are never good and pretty much always screw everything up in code. Don't make typos. It should display a message in the Sublime console every time it loads/reloads the plugin, and it should print out error messages if there are any typos in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this didn't work for me at first because there were some other plugins "before" this one that were trying to import "sublimePlugin" which my ST3 Win7 instance didn't like.  I had to import "sublime_plugin".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old but another stupid error I ran in to was that when I saved my file i accidently saved it as a py3 file and not a py file, duh!